# Attach callback method to Polymer element property

Tags: callback, polymer

I need to do something like this:

```
<polymer-element name="base-page">
<template>
    <my-element>
        styleCallback="{{getStyle}}"
    </my-element>
</template>
<script>
    Polymer({
        getStyle: function(data) {
            return {
                color: "#FF0000"
            }
        }
    });
</script>
</polymer-element>
<base-page></base-page>
```

Where the my-element calls out into the getStyle function to get an object that it can then use to do its internal processing. I am not sure how I do that in above. Can anyone help? Thanks :-)

Best Regards
Justin Case

Answer (score 0):

When do you want to use this ? Maybe you can handle this by the lifecycle events and data binding.

For example :

```js
<polymer-element name="base-page">
<template>
    <my-element>
        styleCallback="{{color}}"
    </my-element>
</template>
<script>
    Polymer({
        created: function() {
                this.color: "#FF0000";
        }
    });
</script>
</polymer-element>
<base-page></base-page>
```

Hope I understand you right :)

Comment: Thanks, I understand what you are suggesting, However inside the my-element, I have a loop that loops over multiple items and for each item I want to call the function in the base-page element that then holds the specific implementation to return a style.